# replace \n with actual new line character code

Tags: php, utf-8, newline

I'm pulling content from a DB that has been sanitized using mysql_real_escape_string.
Accordingly the new line characters now appear as "\n".
The issue is that this content is displayed to users inside a < pre > tag so I cannot replace \n with < br/> for instance.

I suppose I could replace \n with the actual utf8 character code before inserting the result inside the < pre>.

Can somoneone assist here? Not using mysql_real_escape_string isn't really an option due to security policy.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled, normally your data should be returned unescaped. The way you describe it, it's as if the data went through mysql_real_escape_string() twice before being stored

Comment: It actually sounds like you over-sanitized the data by escaping it twice. If you put in `mysql_real_escape_string("two\nlines");` there will be a real `\n` character in the database. If you get data out, there should be no need to replace `\n` back. If you keep it this way, expect problems with ' and " as well.

Comment: maybe you're a victim of the ludicrous "magic_quote" functionality in php - make sure that you disable it, it only confuses those who are aware of the concept of escaping.

Comment: Indeed it looks like the data was escaped twice. I'm using Zend_db and it seems that it's using mysql_real_escape_string by default.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
echo '<pre>'.str_replace('\n', "\n", $string).'</pre>';
```

Comment: this would work as a 'quick fix'. The root cause is the data being escaped twice

Comment: This didn't work until I used double quotes `"\n"` instead of single quotes `'\n'` for some reason.

Answer (score 7):

why not ...

```
echo str_replace('\\n', PHP_EOL, "few lines\nof text here,\nblah, blah! etc!");
```

Answer (score 6):

```
str_replace("\\n","\n",$data);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm pulling content from a DB that has been sanitized using mysql_real_escape_string. Accordingly the new line characters now appear as "\n"

If you've not done anything to the raw data pulled back from the database then the ptoblem is that it has been 'sanitized' twice when inserted.

C.

Answer (score -2):

This might help a bit:

echo('test\ntest');
shows as

**test test**

but
echo("test\ntest");
shows as

**test**

**test**

Comment: echo('test\ntest'); should appear as test\ntest