# How to replace `\n` with new line when print as <pre> in HTML?

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

I get text file from PHP server that looks like:

> "File version: 5\n\nstart:    1410355285955(2014/09/10 11:58:05.955)\nend:      141090402750(2014/09/10 12:00:02.750)\nUEID:     301660031\nCNC:      118130\nVendor:   75306\nModel:    807182328\nOS:       1549568403\nPlatform: 1\nCarrier:  -1337093915\nReported Networks:  0\n\nNum domains: 1\n  Domain 276975141\n    Num tags: 1\n      -2032188703\n    Num hostedApps: 2\n     HostedApp: -2097733624,  HostedVersion 300009300500000, ...

How to replace `\n` with new line?

Expected result should be:

```
File version: 5

start:    1410450285955(2014/09/10 11:58:05.955)
end:      1413350402750(2014/09/10 12:00:02.750)
UEID:     301600031
CNC:      114130
Vendor:   75506
Model:    827112328
OS:       1539568403
Platform: 1
Carrier:  -1347083915
Reported Networks:  0

Num domains: 1
  Domain 276955141
  Num tags: 1
  -2032160703
  Num hostedApps: 2
  HostedApp: -2052733624,  HostedVersion 3000003070500000, ...
```

I print it as:

```
 <pre>{{myText}}</pre>
```

If it was json, I would use `json` filter:

```
 <pre>{{myText | json}}</pre>
```

---

This is how I open file in PHP:

```
 $file = file_get_contents($filePath, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
```

Comment: Maybe `$file = nl2br(file_get_contents($filePath, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH));` ?

Comment: If it's going in a `pre`, then you shouldn't need to replace the `\n` since that *is* the newline. http://jsfiddle.net/00s3w6mo/

Comment: @squint  Ohh, my fault, somehow I didn't think about, and added other code that break this. thank you. please post this answer for accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's going in a `pre`, then you shouldn't need to replace the `\n` since that *is* the newline.

```js
document.querySelector("pre").textContent = "File version: 5\n\nstart: 1410355285955(2014/09/10 11:58:05.955)\nend: 141090402750(2014/09/10 12:00:02.750)\nUEID: 301660031\nCNC: 118130\nVendor: 75306\nModel: 807182328\nOS: 1549568403\nPlatform: 1\nCarrier: -1337093915\nReported Networks: 0\n\nNum domains: 1\n Domain 276975141\n Num tags: 1\n -2032188703\n Num hostedApps: 2\n HostedApp: -2097733624, HostedVersion 300009300500000, ..."
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's odd that the newline character `\n` is being included literally into the text. It might be double escaped somewhere.

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264270/replace-n-with-actual-new-line-character-code)

In this case for a fix you just need to replace the newline character in single quotes `'\n'` with a newline in double quotes `"\n"` so it will be interpreted correctly in PHP. Try using PHP's `str_replace()` for that.